# How to deploy a web app with encrypted source code?

Tags: web-applications, encryption

I have created a web application in my "localhost" that is solely dependent on a number of js, html and css files within the server, so I can run it offline provided I have the files in the local folder. The app is designed to work with major browsers (Chrome/Firefox) on computers and tablets.

To protect my work from illegal reproduction, I'm looking for a way to **encrypt the source code**, but still be able to use the application using Chrome at least.

The app will be deployed to a wide audience so I don't want to see my app with different names somewhere else.

Is this possible by any means?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way to lock your code. You can disable right clicks or obfuscate your code, but it will always be there for replication.

Comment: Pleas don't try to disable right clicks though... Anyone with a tiny bit of knowledge can bypass that little piece of JS and it just bothers your real users.

Comment: Also, while your html/css/js/etc can't be encrypted, the way you generate it should should still remain secure as long as your server that the backend runs on is. That's as close as you can get though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to the degree that you want.

But what you are looking for is an obfuscator -

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscateprotect-javascript) - and then have a look at [this tool](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/)